# How to target / apply styles to an image loaded from Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, image, position, css-position

I installed a SSL trust logo onto my website – the following code is what displays the logo:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
TrustLogo("https://www.(mywebsite).com/comodo_secure_seal_76x26_transp.png", "CL1", "none");
</script>
```

I needed it to be *fixed* on the bottom left corner of my page, so after a lot of trial and error I settled with the following code:

```
img:not(main img) {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
```

The problem is, this isn't really targeting the *specific* image that needs to be targeted. The bigger problem is that this **does not work** on any other browser other than the browser I had originally tested (Safari). (Maybe it's because the 'img' tag is not appropriate targeting?)

How can I target this logo? (If not through CSS, how can I make it fixed?)

Safari (the CSS works here)=> [image: Safari (the CSS works here)]

Chrome (CSS does nothing)=> [image: Chrome (does not work)]

Comment: Take a look at the resulting html  from the function using the node inspector, specifically any class="something", then use the class selector in your css such as 'img.classname'  Also, in the future, use something like codepen to mock up your problem and you will get a much better response :)

Comment: I didn't know what a node inspector was but I did the inspection and found a lot of useful data! I was able to solve my problem simply by targeting the _src_ (duh!). Thanks for helping

Comment: Can't you just put that image in a div and target that class? Targeting the src seems no bueno.

Comment: It's loaded through javascript so I can't apply a class (did not work) and wrapping it in a div with a class/id did not work either =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

Do not use `img` to target the logo – use one of the image's *attrributes* to be as specific as possible.

Try something as simple as the `src` attribute:

`[src="https://www.(mywebsite).com/comodo_secure_seal_76x26_transp.png"]`

You can also use a node inspector to view more useful information to help you pinpoint the image.

Comment: Hey @Cris - maybe you shouldn't delete your questions while people are spending their valuable time answering them: https://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/a88b66fa934e4abbd38e054a45d3f2ff/

Comment: @sheriffderek what??

Comment: Your other question that I was answering said it was removed when I tried to submit my answer, but I think it was a glitch - because I see it there now. Weird.... : /